# Symmetries of the singular vectors of the line graph

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the matrix $$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \ & \ddots &  & \ddots & \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \end{matrix} \right) $$

This question is about the singular vectors of $A$, i.e., the eigenvectors of $A^T A$. Ill denote them by $v_1, \ldots, v_n$. Suppose $n$ is even, and let $P$ be the permutation matrix which flips the vector around the midpoint, i.e., $P$ flips entries $1$ and $n$, entries $2$ and $n-1$, and finally entries $n/2$ and $n/2+1$.

**Observation:** A few numerical experiments in MATLAB suggest that *exactly half* of the $v_i$ satisfy $Pv=-v$ and the remainder satisfy $Pv=v$.

**My question:** Can someone provide an explanation for why this is the case?

**Update:** I suppose I should note that it isn't surprising that we can find eigenvectors which satisfy either $Pv=v$ or $Pv=-v$. Indeed, we can go through the list of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ and if $Pv_i \neq v_i$, then because $Pv_i$ is also an eigenvector of $A^T A$ with the same eigenvalue, we can replace $v_i$ with $v_i'=v_i+Pv_i, v_i''=v_i-Pv_i$; then $Pv_i' = v_i', Pv_i'' = -v_i''$; finally we can throw out the redundant vectors. What **is** surprising to me is that the orthogonal basis returned by the MATLAB eig command has *exactly half* of the vectors which satisfy $Pv=v$ and *exactly half* which satisfy $Pv=-v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vectors (general vectors, not eigenvectors) with either kind of parity form $n/2$-dimensional subspaces. For instance, a basis for the even vectors is $(1,0,0,\dotsc,0,0,1)$, $(0,1,0,\dots,0,1,0)$, $\dotsc$

You've already explained that we can choose an eigenbasis for $A$ in which all vectors have definite parity. Since there can be at most $n/2$ of either kind, there must be exactly $n/2$ of either kind.

Comment: Thanks, this explains 95% of what I am asking for. One small thing still requires an explanation though. I can see that one can pick a  basis of eigenvectors of $A^T A$ such that for half of them $Pv=v$ and for half of them $Pv=-v$. But how to show that you can pick an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors with the same property?

Comment: @robinson: Eigenvectors for different eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix ($A^TA$ is symmetric) are orthogonal, and vectors of different parity are orthogonal So the only choice lies in eigenvectors with the same parity and the same eigenvalue; since any linear combination of these again has the same parity and eigenvalue, you can simply orthogonalize them.